# Laravel Command - break param description into two lines

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I use Laravel 5.8. In one of my artisan command files I have a parameter with quiet long description, which I would like to break into 2 lines:

```
class GenerateReport extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'report:generate
                            {--myparam : long description to be broken into several lines}';
```

I tried `\n` and `<br>`, but both are printed out as text.
For example, if I add `\n` after the word *description* the output of `php artisan report:generate -h` is:

```
Description:
  Command description...

Usage:
  report:generate [options]

Options:
      --myparam         long description\nto be broken into several lines
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

I also dived into vendor code, but could not figure out how to do it (in some place I could not continue following the code).

I found [this article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/style.html), but it seems this is not applied on the `$signature` printing.

Any idea?

Comment: Also, `\n` only adds a newline for `"`, but yours is wrapped in `'`. Sidenote, I see the issue you're talking about now; if you break the description of that `{ --myparam= : ...}` onto another line, the option is no longer available.

Comment: @TimLewis, just updated my question

Comment: Much better   Yeah, if you try to use `"` instead of `'` with `\n` somewhere in there, you'll notice the `--myparam` Option ends up missing from the list. I don't know if you can multi-line the param description here. Do you really need to though? I get that line length in PHP should be short, but it might be unavoidable here.

Comment: I'm aware that this is a very rare case. I guess the idea is to focus in short description, but I have one parameter which is more complicated, and I would like to print its detailed description with the `-h` option.

Comment: Yeah, for sure, I understand the need here. If you leave it as a single line in your code, it should still split out to new lines in your Terminal: `'{--test : skdjfhkjskdh ... }'` results in this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaGBz.png

Comment: Exactly @TimLewis. I wonder if I have to live with this result or there is anything I can do (without modifying the vendor code of course :-) )

Comment: I hear ya. It's tricky too since `$signature` is a class variable. If it wasn't, you could do something like `$signature = "test:test {--test= : $longDescription}"` for interpolation, but that doesn't work here: "Constant expression contains invalid operations" (string interpolation is not available at that point in runtime). I'd say keep poking at it, see what you can find out, but it might be a lost cause 